# Why doesn't the plot generated by Plotly in a Jupyter Notebook display after I upload it on Github?

Tags: python, github, plot, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I plotted a figure in Jupyter Notebook using **Plotly**, and it displayed all right locally. However, nothing showed up below the code chunk after I upload the **Jupyter Notebook** to one of my repositories on **Github**. Is this just the way it is, or did I miss something? How can I make the figure seen?

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = list()
COLORS = ["aqua","sienna","coral","darkgreen","darksalmon",
          "darkslateblue","greenyellow","maroon","violet"]

for county, col in zip(COUNTIES,COLORS):
    trace = go.Scatter(x = DF.columns,
                       y = DF.loc[county,:],
                       name = county,
                       line = dict(color = col),
                       opacity = 0.8)
    data.append(trace)

fig = go.Figure(data = data,
                layout = dict(title = "County-level (Normalized) Daily New Cases"))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image in the Jupyter Notebook is generated by running code, then GitHub won't render it.  GitHub doesn't execute code from users or permit user-provided JavaScript when rendering files, because doing so is a security risk.  User-provided code could be used to steal credentials, attack other servers, or otherwise do a wide variety of nefarious things.

So the answer is that this is just the way it is.

Comment: Additionally note - you can export your notebook to a static format prior to upload to GitHub if you'd like it to render. See https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook.html#notebook-documents

Comment: @RamiMac  Thanks! That's very helpful!